# Batch script to create folder based on part of filename then copy files to specific folder

Tags: batch-file

Currently, I have this script up and running:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FolderIncoming=D:\Recordings\Calls\All_Calls
set FileMask=201*.wav
set FolderSorted=D:\Recordings\ODrive - Mitus\CallRecordings
Set LameLocation=C:\Program Files (x86)\Lame

for %%a in ("%FolderIncoming%\%FileMask%") do (
   set FileName=%%~na
   set TargetYear=!FileName:~0,4!
   set TargetFolder=!TargetYear!\!FileName:~0,10!
            if not exist "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!\%%~na.mp3" (
               echo Processing '!FileName!' ...
               if not exist "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!" md "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!"
               "%LameLocation%\lame.exe" -V9 --vbr-new -mm -h -q 0 "%%a" "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!\%%~na.mp3"
            )
)
```

It's working perfectly fine but how can I add the feature where it will place each converted wav file to specific folder location based on IP Extensions. Right now, we 7 IP extensions (10200, 10201, 10202, 10203, 10204, 10205, 10206) and I want it be be saved in folders as:

```
IP Extension\Date\Converted_wav-to-mp3_Files_Here
```

Examples of saved recording name:

```
2015-04-10-08-52-15_xxxxxxxxxxxx_10201.mp3
2015-04-10-10-03-52_10202_xxxxxxxxxxx.mp3
```

Files should be saved, respectively, in appropriate folders as follows:

```
10201\2015-04-10\2015-04-10-08-52-15_xxxxxxxxxxxx_10201.mp3
10202\2015-04-10\2015-04-10-10-03-52_10202_xxxxxxxxxxx.mp3
```

It's a bit puzzling since extensions begins, in-between, or ended with `_` (underscore).

Here's what I do so far but it does not include the extension when it creates the folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set extensions=/10200/10210/10220/10230/10240/10250/10260/
set FolderIncoming=D:\Recordings\Calls\All_Calls
set FileMask=201*.wav
set FolderSorted=D:\Recordings\ODrive - Mitus\CallRecordings
Set LameLocation=C:\Program Files (x86)\Lame

for %%a in ("%FolderIncoming%\%FileMask%") do (

   set FileName=%%~na

   for %%b in (!Filename:_= !) do (
      if "!extensions:/%%b/=!" neq "%extensions%" set "extension=%%b"
   )

   set TargetYear=!FileName:~0,4!
   set TargetFolder=!extension!\!TargetYear!\!FileName:~0,10!

            if not exist "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!\%%~na.mp3" (
               echo Processing '!FileName!' ...
               if not exist "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!" md "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!"
          REM"%LameLocation%\lame.exe" -m j --cbr -b 320 -q 0 --lowpass 22.05 "%%a" "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!\%%~na.mp3"
               "%LameLocation%\lame.exe" -V9 --vbr-new -mm -h -q 0 "%%a" "%FolderSorted%\!TargetFolder!\%%~na.mp3"
            )

)
```

What changes should this have to make it working as it should be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet could work:

```
set "FileName=%%~na"
set "NameFile=!Filename:_= !"

set "extension=abcde"
rem this will not resolve: for %%b in (!Filename:_= !)
for %%b in (!NameFile!) do (
   if "!extensions:/%%b/=!" neq "%extensions%" set "extension=%%b"
)
if "!extension!"=="abcde" echo !Filename! does not match desired extensions
```

However, in your `set extensions=/10200/10210/10220/10230/10240/10250/10260/` does not occur any of proposed 10201, 10202, 10203, 10204, 10205, 10206...

Thus, there is another possible mechanism:

```
set "FileName=%%~na"
set "NameFile=!Filename:_= !"

set "extension=abcde"
for %%b in (!NameFile!) do (
   set "strFragment=%%b"
   rem if "!strFragment:-=!" equ "!strFragment!" ( set /A "numExtens=%%b") else ( set /A "numExtens=0")
   set /A "numExtens=!strFragment:-0=-!"
   if !numExtens! geq 10200 if !numExtens! leq 10299 set "extension=%%b"
)
if "!extension!"=="abcde" echo !Filename! out of desired range
```

Note substitution in `set /A "numExtens=!strFragment:-0=-!"`. Treats possible invalid octal value in datetime e.g. `2015-04-09-08-52-15` as `set /A numvar=08` (or `set /A numvar=09` as well) causes an exception with next error message: `Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).` and `numvar` keeps unchanged.

A *flash*: maybe there is better approach:

```
set /A "numExtens=0"
set /A "numExtens=!strFragment!" 2>NUL
```

That is more universal, could work for nearly any `xxxxxxxxxxxx` filename part...